# Jquery Category Updating System with HTML Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, categories

I am making a system where you use the `<select>` and `<option>` value as a support system. I am trying to make it where if you click on Donations it will load text and then remove that after something else is selected.

How could I do this? I want to do it in Jquery and I am new to it.

```
<select style="width:200px;">
  <option value="Ban Appeal">Ban Appeal</option>
  <option value="Donation">Donation</option>
  <option value="Report a Player">Report a Player</option>
  <option value="Staff Report">Staff Report</option>
  <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
  <option value="Forgot Pass?">Forgot Pass?</option>
  <option value="Apply for Staff">Apply for Staff</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Anyone? I really need help please

Comment: Just bind a change event with select. If its value is 'Donation' do something otherwise do something else.

Comment: where to load text? can you post more html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on change event and do what you want.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<select style="width:200px;" onchange="if(this.value=='Donation')a();else b();">
  <option selected value="">select any one</option>
  <option value="Ban Appeal">Ban Appeal</option>
  <option value="Donation">Donation</option>
  <option value="Report a Player">Report a Player</option>
  <option value="Staff Report">Staff Report</option>
  <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
  <option value="Forgot Pass?">Forgot Pass?</option>
  <option value="Apply for Staff">Apply for Staff</option>
</select>
<div id="message"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(){
    $("#message").text("Donation selected");
}
function b(){
    $("#message").text("Other then donation selected");
}
</script>
```

```js
function displaymsg(value){
        switch(value) {
            case "Ban Appeal":
                $("#message").text("Ban Appeal description");
                break;
            case "Donation":
                $("#message").text("Donation description");
                break;
            case "Report a Player":
                $("#message").text("Report a Player description");
                break;
            case "Staff Report":
                $("#message").text("Staff Report description");
                break;
            case "Suggestion":
                $("#message").text("Suggestion description");
                break;
            default:
                $("#message").text("");
        } 
    }
```

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <select style="width:200px;" onchange="displaymsg(this.value)">
      <option selected value="">select any one</option>
      <option value="Ban Appeal">Ban Appeal</option>
      <option value="Donation">Donation</option>
      <option value="Report a Player">Report a Player</option>
      <option value="Staff Report">Staff Report</option>
      <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
      <option value="Forgot Pass?">Forgot Pass?</option>
      <option value="Apply for Staff">Apply for Staff</option>
    </select>
    <div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to may this alert display on the page?

Comment: You need to use .text() or .html() on any div/span or p tag.

Comment: Can this be made into multiple ones lets say i want it to say when they select Donation and then i seelect apply

Comment: don't understand by "they select Donation and then i seelect apply", multiple dropdown selected as 'Donation' and one apply button. who will select those dropdown and who will select apply.

Comment: so what i want to do is when they select donation it gives them a description on donation support and that dissapears when they click another category it displays that description and so on

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Sorry for bugging you though :(